# Multiprocessing assign multiple jobs on multiple CPUs (each has multiple cores) in PBS

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pbs

The job is to count 10 on a grid (16 x 16). A shared `dict` *Library* is monitoring. Code is here:

```
import json
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from itertools import product


def func(point, limit, pause, Library):
    while True:
        if Library[point] >= limit:
            break
        time.sleep(pause)
        Library[point] += pause
        pass
    pass


def main():
    limit = 10
    pause = 1
    points = list(product(range(16), range(16)))
    Library = mp.Manager().dict()
    Library.update({point: 0 for point in points })
    pool = mp.Pool()
    t0 = time.time()
    for point in points:
        pool.apply_async(func, args=[point, limit, pause, Library])
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    duration = round(time.time()-t0, 2)
    print(duration)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pass
```

I run it on a server with multiple nodes. Each node has multiple (≥16) CPUs and each CPU has 16 cores. I assume if this script `tasks.py` is run on 16 CPUs, then each core will be assigned a process. So the runtime should be around 10 seconds. The PBS file is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N tasks
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=16
#PBS -l partition=std
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
#PBS -o logs/output/tasks.o
#PBS -e logs/error/tasks.e

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

python tasks.py
```

Yet I am wrong. The runtime is 160.72 seconds. There seems to be only one CPU working. Is there a way to run multiprocessing script on multiple CPUs in PBS? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about `processpoolexcutor`? It seems to me that your code runs only one process at a time.

Comment: Still a GIL problem. Python forbids you for accessing shared memory in multiprocessing. So once you put the `Library` into the `apply_async`, it will no longer work.

Comment: @Natthaphon Hongcharoen Thanks for response. The result is 160.28 seconds. There seems to be nothing different.

Comment: @MT-FreeHK Thanks for response. Yet isn't multiprocessing supposed to work on process instead of thread? I don't think this is related to GIL.

Comment: @jianchang , no, multiprocessing is not bypassing the GIL. And GIL is not simply mean it locks up your thread, but a protection towards memory sharing. So, no memory sharing is fundamental rule.

Comment: Try using `map` and do your summation after multiprocessing, it will works.

Comment: @MT-FreeHK I'll think about it. Thanks.